# notify application when a particular table value changes in the database

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using struts2,i want my application to be notified when the values of particular table changes in the mssql 2008 r2 database.Can anyone explain?

Comment: Have you found anything out yet in your research? Database triggers can be set up to respond to data events.  Alternatively, you can poll your database for changes if you would prefer to maintain control from the app.

Comment: Question: changed by your application or changed by someone else? Have you tried something?

Comment: What sort of interfaces does your application expose? You will definitely need a trigger, or if your updates are done via stored procs you can emit something there; however depending on what your application exposes from here the implementation will be very much specific to what you can accept

Answer (score 0):

best solution is to use cron, async method which sun in the background,
create one trigger for particular table where u required to get a update from,
which store the data in one notification table using time stamp, the cron will automatically fire on specific time of duration like 2 min after(2000 miliseconds), this continues cron running process will notify every 2 min after any database changes (as notification)

Comment: Depending on the number of instances polling and the size of the query this could potentially grind the database to halt

Comment: Leon, but it must follow one of the above solution, apart from the other way its hard to traverse the wall record when you want notification, is there any better way to solved the problem of 
user3804142